# Building golang microservice gRPC Docker image

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, microservices

I am struggling to build a docker image for golang microservice project with gRPC but it is failing how do I go about it?

Here is my project structure.

`projectDir->services->[app-proto, app-db, app-auth]`

My generated protos golang files are inside `app-proto` dir and I import them in app-db microservice go.mod file as below

```
go 1.16
require (

....
github.com/marvinhosea/tuma-app-proto/db v0.0.0

...
)

replace github.com/marvinhosea/tuma-app-proto/db => ../app-protos/db
```

and here is my docker file

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

And here is the error that am getting

```
go: github.com/marvinhosea/tuma-app-proto/db@v0.0.0 (replaced by ../app-proto/db): reading /app-protos/db/go.mod: open /app-proto/db/go.mod: no such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @LunaLovegood added the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Docker build context does not include the relative path you use with the `replace` directive used in `go.mod`.

Assuming your directory structure is something like this:

```
app-proto/
app-proto/db/defs.pb.go
app-proto/db/defs.proto

tuma-app-proto/
tuma-app-proto/db/Dockerfile
tuma-app-proto/db/go.mod
tuma-app-proto/db/go.sum
tuma-app-proto/db/*.go
```

and running your docker build from `tuma-app-proto/db/`:

```
docker build -t myimage .    # . indicates the docker context directory
```

this will see your main go code but **NOT** your protobuf directory (`app-proto/db/`). (You cannot use `..` from the docker context root and see a higher-level directory)

The simplest solution would be to move your context higher up - and naturally your `Dockerfile` too - to encompass both directories. e.g.

```
Dockerfile

app-proto/db/
tuma-app-proto/db/
```

and update your Dockerfile's `COPY` to use this new path structure:

```
#
# copy proto files
#
WORKDIR /app/app-proto/db
COPY app-proto/db/* ./ 

#
# copy go code:
#
WORKDIR /app/tuma-app-proto/db
COPY tuma-app-proto/db/* ./ 

RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o main .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

Comment: Lemme give it a shot then I will update you. Thank you

Comment: Any luck @Marvin?